# mysql2-0.3.11 can not be installed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab

Hi 
 I want to install Gitlab on Debian 7.0 when i want to install the bundle i get follor error by **mysql2-0.3.11**

```
    root@v22013051598612672:/home/git/gitlab# gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'
    Fetching: mysql2-0.3.11.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lm... yes
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lz... yes
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lsocket... no
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.



   Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 /gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspecti                                                on.
   Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I have you a idea?

Mfg user2182545 (ternes3)

PS: I need it for GitLAB

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mysql + libraries via `apt-get install mysql-server libmysqlclient libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client mysql-common`

Answer (score 0):

The [issue 754](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/754) mentions seeing this error even after `gem install mysql2` and `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`.
But it also adds:

> EDIT: Solved!

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient16-dev
```

Check if this is the actual missing piece on your Debian.